# Laravel Flash Message not displaying message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I was to trying to show flash message with following controller. But it's not displaying any message on view page.

```
public function deleteTag(Request $request)
    {
        DB::table('tags')
            ->where('id', $request->id)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->delete();
        Session::flash('error', 'Tag deleted successfully' );
        return redirect('tags');
    }
```

In view part:

```
   @if (Session::has('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-primary inline-form-alert d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between table-alert">
            <ul>
                <li class="alert-icon-content"><i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill me-2"></i>{{ Session('error') }}</li>
            </ul> 
           <button class="btn-close ms-3" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
         </div>
     @endif
```

In same page following controller flash message is showing. Why flash message not displaying on delete controller?

```
public function storeTag(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'tag_name' => [
                Rule::unique('tags')->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                })
            ],
        ]);

        $tag = new Tag();
        $tag->tag_name = $request->Input(['tag_name']);
        $tag->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $tag->save();

        Session::flash('error', 'Tag created successfully' );

        return redirect('tags');
    }
```

Comment: did your route inside middleware `web` ?

Comment: test sessions with the command `php artisan session:test` check if any error occurred and any middleware on your route that affects sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Docs Link](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

You can redirect to route with the flash message.

You need to check first that if data is delete successful if yes then send success otherwise send error

```
public function deleteTag(Request $request)
    {
        $result = DB::table('tags')
            ->where('id', $request->id)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->delete();
        if($result == true){
             return redirect('tags')->with('success', 'Tag deleted successfully');
        }else{
            return redirect('tags')->with('error', 'Something Went Wrong');
        }
    }
```

In the `view section` you can add this code and one thing you must be check that this code is need to write where the `redirect('tags')` route load the view.

```
    @if (session('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-primary inline-form-alert d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between table-alert">
                <ul>
                    <li class="alert-icon-content"><i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill me-2"></i>{{ session('success') }}</li>
                </ul> 
               <button class="btn-close ms-3" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
             </div>
         @elseif (session('error'))
             <div class="alert alert-primary inline-form-alert d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between table-alert">
                <ul>
                    <li class="alert-icon-content"><i class="bi bi-exclamation-circle-fill me-2"></i>{{ session('error') }}</li>
                </ul> 
               <button class="btn-close ms-3" type="button" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
             </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: I have tried with your code. It doesn't show any error message.

Comment: did you add this code in the view where you redirect the request? can you check this?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that this line** Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class, **stays commented or removed in the Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,

    ],
```